# What's the quickest way to import a large data set into a database?

Tags: database

The two options I'm considering are index and then import vs importing and then indexing.  Is there one method that is significantly faster?

Comment: In my experience, it depends upon the amount of data, and how it is formatted prior to import. If it is already in the correct order for structural indexes (clustered index in SQL Server), then putting the index on first is probably quicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, for large inserts, it is better to insert then index.

Otherwise the insert process will need to insert *while* indexing, which will be slow and get slower and slower as more items are added.

Consider an shuffled deck of cards - what would be faster? Taking all of the cards and sorting them in place or taking each card one at a time and putting it in place in a new pile? (not the best analogy, I know).